# create a contour plot from data in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: matlab, plot, contour, colorbar, contourf

Here is my problem. I have some data in excel format organized in three columns of x, y, z values. I would like to create a 2d contour plot on the x-y plane in matlab. The 'x' and 'y' are coordinates of the shape and 'z' is stress of different nodes of the shape. Any column has 6k rows. Here is part of my excel columns:

```
337.67  -1.2    1.27
337.67  -1.6    4.067
338     -1.6    0.48198
338     -1.2    0.27969
338     -0.8    0.37517
338     -0.4    0.24372
338.34  -1.6    -3.66E-01
338.34  -1.2    7.15E-02
338.34  -0.8    0.14178
338.34  -0.4    0.23041
303.23  1.6667  -2.3408
303.23  1.3333  -1.09E+00
300     2       8.03E-02
300.4   2       -0.47371
300.81  2       -3.411
301.21  2       -4.6577
301.62  2       -4.7701
302.02  2       -4.576
302.42  2       -4.2941
302.83  2       -4.1048
300     1.6667  5.0174
300     1.3333  -12.041
300.4   1.3333  -6.4757
300.4   1.6667  -2.8059
300.81  1.3333  -4.4965
300.81  1.6667  -3.8025
301.21  1.3333  -4.2531
301.21  1.6667  -4.1463
301.62  1.3333  -4.0889
301.62  1.6667  -4.3331
302.02  1.3333  -3.7846
302.02  1.6667  -4.1606
302.42  1.3333  -3.2634
302.42  1.6667  -3.818
302.83  1.3333  -2.4646
302.83  1.6667  -3.3398
303.85  1.6667  5.1077
303.85  1.3333  1.7428
303.44  1.6667  -1.2232
303.64  1.6667  2.06E+00
303.44  1.3333  -3.24E-02
303.64  1.3333  0.95421
304.2   2       19.405
304.2   1.6667  0.20742
304.2   1.3333  2.2959
309.8   1.6667  1.4379
309.8   1.3333  0.42799
309.2   2       1.8717
309.5   2       24.488
309.2   1.6667  15.513
309.2   1.3333  7.7083
309.5   1.3333  4.9854
309.5   1.6667  -5.2054
311.6   1.6667  64.433
311.6   1.3333  26.935
311.24  1.3333  10.86
310.88  1.3333  -6.5021
310.52  1.3333  -8.0571
310.16  1.3333  -3.5606
311.24  1.6667  -20.236
310.88  1.6667  -29.1
310.52  1.6667  -20.445
310.16  1.6667  -9.8013
312.2   2       27.465
311.9   2       112.82
312.2   1.3333  36.599
312.2   1.6667  21.912
311.9   1.3333  49.795
311.9   1.6667  27.24
317.13  1.6667  81.881
317.13  1.3333  36.009
316.53  2       31.95
316.53  1.6667  21.34
316.53  1.3333  30.858
316.83  2       143.46
316.83  1.6667  36.532
316.83  1.3333  57.438
318.93  1.6667  103.96
318.93  1.3333  60.877
317.49  1.3333  22.27
317.49  1.6667  -15.704
317.85  1.3333  3.4891
317.85  1.6667  -2.20E+01
318.21  1.3333  7.13E-02
318.21  1.6667  -3.4699
318.57  1.3333  4.5517
318.57  1.6667  37.118
319.53  2       4.4242
319.53  1.3333  81.393
319.53  1.6667  7.6617
319.23  2       16.162
319.23  1.3333  104.77
319.23  1.6667  92.785
323.86  2       5.9245
323.86  1.6667  6.7662
323.86  1.3333  78.857
324.46  1.6667  109.98
324.46  1.3333  63.953
324.16  2       15.844
324.16  1.6667  95.389
324.16  1.3333  99.019
326.26  1.6667  76.125
326.26  1.3333  32.991
324.82  1.3333  13.334
324.82  1.6667  46.345
325.18  1.3333  -4.3734
325.18  1.6667  -2.9013
325.54  1.3333  -2.8997
325.54  1.6667  -21.213
325.9   1.3333  15.317
325.9   1.6667  -16.696
326.86  2       31.352
326.56  2       120.87
326.86  1.3333  40.968
326.86  1.6667  17.418
326.56  1.3333  57.251
326.56  1.6667  36.112
331.79  1.6667  45.649
331.79  1.3333  32.694
331.19  2       2.4097
331.49  2       2.8176
331.19  1.6667  0.91089
331.19  1.3333  20.491
331.49  1.3333  35.743
331.49  1.6667  30.927
333.59  1.6667  10.617
333.59  1.3333  4.2469
332.15  1.3333  26.014
332.15  1.6667  37.107
332.51  1.3333  13.04
332.51  1.6667  15.951
332.87  1.3333  4.0499
332.87  1.6667  3.339
333.23  1.3333  3.2276
333.23  1.6667  0.52933
334.19  2       3.9746
333.89  2       15.458
334.19  1.3333  4.6277
334.19  1.6667  1.4797
333.89  1.3333  7.038
333.89  1.6667  5.0961
339.27  1.6667  0.87739
339.27  1.3333  5.82E-01
338.97  2       -7.36E-04
338.97  1.6667  0.33103
338.97  1.3333  0.45254
339.89  1.6667  1.4007
339.89  1.3333  1.0124
339.48  1.3333  0.7396
339.48  1.6667  1.207
339.68  1.3333  0.89163
339.68  1.6667  1.3416
343.12  2       0.2232
342.72  2       0.38825
342.31  2       1.3951
341.91  2       1.7695
341.5   2       1.788
341.1   2       1.7985
340.7   2       1.8063
340.29  2       1.8131
343.12  1.6667  -1.2768
343.12  1.3333  14.39
342.72  1.3333  4.1008
342.31  1.3333  2.2346
341.91  1.3333  1.6345
341.5   1.3333  1.3715
341.1   1.3333  1.2754
340.7   1.3333  1.2244
340.29  1.3333  1.155
342.72  1.6667  3.4852
342.31  1.6667  2.2269
341.91  1.6667  1.7845
341.5   1.6667  1.6313
341.1   1.6667  1.549
340.7   1.6667  1.5131
340.29  1.6667  1.4751
299     -2      3.6849
299.33  -2      4.8869
299.67  -2      40.211
299     0       0.68276
299.33  0       2.8061
299.67  0       10.159
299     -0.4    2.4884
299     -0.8    3.2572
299     -1.2    4.1301
299     -1.6    4.2724
299.33  -1.6    0.20727
299.33  -1.2    1.0084
299.33  -0.8    0.44557
299.33  -0.4    -0.49267
299.67  -1.6    4.166
299.67  -1.2    6.5929
299.67  -0.8    3.512
299.67  -0.4    1.2939
300     8.18    14.274
303.23  8.18    88.839
300.4   8.18    0.56003
300.81  8.18    -2.0558
301.21  8.18    -2.6162
301.62  8.18    -2.7516
302.02  8.18    -2.6827
302.42  8.18    -1.8809
302.83  8.18    3.7972
303.23  10.23   0.34786
303.23  9.82    1.9253
303.23  9.41    4.5859
303.23  9       8.4365
303.23  8.59    1.18E+01
300     10.23   -9.50E-03
300.4   10.23   0.92421
300.81  10.23   1.4854
301.21  10.23   1.734
301.62  10.23   1.8796
302.02  10.23   1.9735
302.42  10.23   1.8093
302.83  10.23   1.2507
300     9.82    0.92851
300     9.41    2.7531
300     9       5.4899
300     8.59    9.087
300.4   8.59    1.8799
300.4   9       2.6876
300.4   9.41    2.1868
300.4   9.82    1.5135
300.81  8.59    -1.0506
300.81  9       0.91604
300.81  9.41    1.6125
300.81  9.82    1.6024
301.21  8.59    -1.49E+00
301.21  9       -6.49E-02
301.21  9.41    1.1392
301.21  9.82    1.4682
301.62  8.59    -1.60E+00
301.62  9       -5.69E-02
301.62  9.41    1.2451
301.62  9.82    1.5965
302.02  8.59    -1.3358
302.02  9       1.1151
302.02  9.41    2.0209
302.02  9.82    2.0848
302.42  8.59    1.572
302.42  9       2.9535
302.42  9.41    3.094
302.42  9.82    2.5049
302.83  8.59    9.2955
302.83  9       5.7213
302.83  9.41    3.9169
302.83  9.82    2.4909
339.89  10.23   0.55922
339.89  8.18    -37.372
339.89  9.82    2.4598
339.89  9.41    5.6905
339.89  9       10.435
339.89  8.59    29.682
343.12  8.18    7.8895
340.29  8.18    8.3403
340.7   8.18    2.1729
341.1   8.18    2.5354
341.5   8.18    2.144
341.91  8.18    2.0914
342.31  8.18    1.9214
342.72  8.18    2.5386
343.12  10.23   0.40949
343.12  9.82    1.8112
343.12  9.41    3.6845
343.12  9       5.5632
343.12  8.59    6.8609
340.29  10.23   1.4059
340.7   10.23   1.7185
341.1   10.23   1.6517
341.5   10.23   1.5656
341.91  10.23   1.5754
342.31  10.23   1.4863
342.72  10.23   1.1122
340.29  9.82    2.2984
340.7   9.82    1.6124
341.1   9.82    0.75065
341.5   9.82    0.41496
341.91  9.82    0.80844
342.31  9.82    1.358
342.72  9.82    1.7084
340.29  9.41    2.8832
340.7   9.41    0.5284
341.1   9.41    -0.54035
341.5   9.41    -0.54878
341.91  9.41    -0.41883
342.31  9.41    0.60778
342.72  9.41    1.9486
340.29  9       1.7299
340.7   9       -0.89459
341.1   9       -1.2069
341.5   9       -1.1037
341.91  9       -0.86494
342.31  9       -0.46567
342.72  9       1.4495
340.29  8.59    -0.46844
340.7   8.59    -0.40688
341.1   8.59    -0.37087
341.5   8.59    -2.24E-01
341.91  8.59    -2.86E-02
342.31  8.59    2.36E-02
342.72  8.59    0.35237
300     2.93    -23.005
300.4   2.93    -6.6536
300.81  2.93    -7.1208
301.21  2.93    -6.6261
301.62  2.93    -6.3046
302.02  2.93    -5.2061
302.42  2.93    -4.1874
302.83  2.93    -3.0442
300     2.62    15.284
300     2.31    -0.95696
300.4   2.31    -0.73081
300.4   2.62    -8.2183
300.81  2.31    -5.0998
300.81  2.62    -6.7156
301.21  2.31    -5.9138
301.21  2.62    -6.6447
301.62  2.31    -5.3981
301.62  2.62    -6.0667
302.02  2.31    -4.9284
302.02  2.62    -5.1459
302.42  2.31    -4.5013
302.42  2.62    -4.4363
302.83  2.31    -4.2211
302.83  2.62    -3.7147
300     6.23    -39.16
300.4   6.23    24.13
300.81  6.23    -5.1776
301.21  6.23    -4.6903
301.62  6.23    -6.3178
302.02  6.23    -5.6941
302.42  6.23    -4.8345
302.83  6.23    -3.7705
300     3.3425  17.784
300     3.755   -2.3172
300     4.1675  32.178
300     4.58    -33.074
300     4.9925  34.463
300     5.405   14.725
300     5.8175  46.444
300.4   3.3425  -2.2997
300.4   3.755   1.5783
300.4   4.1675  -5.6894
300.4   4.58    4.4895
300.4   4.9925  4.7917
300.4   5.405   2.32E+00
300.4   5.8175  -4.58E-02
300.81  3.3425  -6.5697
300.81  3.755   -5.5285
300.81  4.1675  -6.76
300.81  4.58    -7.417
300.81  4.9925  -3.7866
300.81  5.405   -5.2265
300.81  5.8175  -5.9105
301.21  3.3425  -6.7089
301.21  3.755   -6.8095
301.21  4.1675  -6.9475
301.21  4.58    -6.9226
301.21  4.9925  -6.8394
301.21  5.405   -6.8615
301.21  5.8175  -6.8386
301.62  3.3425  -6.2766
301.62  3.755   -6.6983
301.62  4.1675  -7.146
301.62  4.58    -7.2729
301.62  4.9925  -6.411
301.62  5.405   -6.8848
301.62  5.8175  -7.4734
302.02  3.3425  -5.1437
302.02  3.755   -5.2374
302.02  4.1675  -5.4181
302.02  4.58    -5.3688
302.02  4.9925  -5.262
302.02  5.405   -5.5879
302.02  5.8175  -5.9688
302.42  3.3425  -3.8488
302.42  3.755   -3.6634
302.42  4.1675  -3.6163
302.42  4.58    -3.5896
302.42  4.9925  -3.6563
302.42  5.405   -3.9912
302.42  5.8175  -4.5057
302.83  3.3425  -2.4411
302.83  3.755   -2.1309
302.83  4.1675  -1.9902
302.83  4.58    -1.9471
302.83  4.9925  -2.0184
302.83  5.405   -2.2935
302.83  5.8175  -2.879
300     7.57    -33.508
300.4   7.57    23.816
300.81  7.57    -0.93111
301.21  7.57    -0.74825
301.62  7.57    -3.4018
302.02  7.57    -3.3524
302.42  7.57    -1.8643
302.83  7.57    7.1021
300     6.565   44.092
300     6.9     26.06
300     7.235   37.65
300.4   6.565   7.6003
300.4   6.9     -1.581
300.4   7.235   6.1098
300.81  6.565   0.19738
300.81  6.9     -4.5491
300.81  7.235   -0.41342
301.21  6.565   -4.3825
301.21  6.9     -4.1917
301.21  7.235   -3.0429
301.62  6.565   -4.8464
301.62  6.9     -4.1152
301.62  7.235   -3.4101
302.02  6.565   -5.0921
302.02  6.9     -4.3217
302.02  7.235   -3.6832
302.42  6.565   -4.6344
302.42  6.9     -3.8475
302.42  7.235   -2.5733
302.83  6.565   -4.1515
302.83  6.9     -3.1935
302.83  7.235   0.43901
303.23  7.875   60.048
300     7.875   33.876
300.4   7.875   5.5342
300.81  7.875   2.0563
301.21  7.875   -2.5728
301.62  7.875   -3.6821
302.02  7.875   -3.9312
302.42  7.875   -1.7307
302.83  7.875   9.659
343.12  2.93    11.364
340.29  2.93    2.8535
340.7   2.93    2.6148
341.1   2.93    2.4007
341.5   2.93    2.209
341.91  2.93    2.1011
342.31  2.93    2.2319
342.72  2.93    3.6567
343.12  6.23    -12.358
343.12  5.8175  10.485
343.12  5.405   -0.87961
343.12  4.9925  0.62426
343.12  4.58    -1.3774
343.12  4.1675  0.18425
343.12  3.755   0.1972
343.12  3.3425  -1.8123
342.72  6.23    -0.9618
342.31  6.23    -2.5652
341.91  6.23    -1.9092
341.5   6.23    -1.50E+00
341.1   6.23    4.63E-02
340.7   6.23    2.4136
340.29  6.23    6.3243
340.29  3.3425  3.3954
340.29  3.755   3.9718
340.29  4.1675  4.575
340.29  4.58    5.1965
340.29  4.9925  5.8069
340.29  5.405   6.3192
340.29  5.8175  6.5466
340.7   3.3425  2.9729
340.7   3.755   3.3095
340.7   4.1675  3.6061
340.7   4.58    3.8346
340.7   4.9925  3.9188
340.7   5.405   3.6984
340.7   5.8175  3.0269
341.1   3.3425  2.6081
341.1   3.755   2.7341
341.1   4.1675  2.7671
341.1   4.58    2.692
341.1   4.9925  2.4127
341.1   5.405   1.7264
341.1   5.8175  0.58484
341.5   3.3425  2.2933
341.5   3.755   2.1992
341.5   4.1675  1.9999
341.5   4.58    1.7293
341.5   4.9925  1.259
341.5   5.405   0.29253
341.5   5.8175  -1.1244
341.91  3.3425  2.0417
341.91  3.755   1.6961
341.91  4.1675  1.2722
341.91  4.58    0.93024
341.91  4.9925  0.50192
341.91  5.405   -0.63674
341.91  5.8175  -1.5982
342.31  3.3425  2.0125
342.31  3.755   0.97764
342.31  4.1675  0.55483
342.31  4.58    2.91E-01
342.31  4.9925  5.81E-02
342.31  5.405   -0.65754
342.31  5.8175  -2.0251
342.72  3.3425  1.9873
342.72  3.755   1.30E-01
342.72  4.1675  6.42E-02
342.72  4.58    -0.30772
342.72  4.9925  -0.12039
342.72  5.405   0.52867
342.72  5.8175  -1.9173
343.12  2.62    -1.41E+00
343.12  2.31    5.76E-02
342.72  2.31    0.20847
342.31  2.31    1.2982
341.91  2.31    1.7588
341.5   2.31    1.9177
341.1   2.31    2.0096
340.7   2.31    2.0752
340.29  2.31    2.1342
342.72  2.62    2.2981
342.31  2.62    1.8324
341.91  2.62    1.8888
341.5   2.62    2.0665
341.1   2.62    2.2104
340.7   2.62    2.3433
340.29  2.62    2.4774
343.12  7.57    -30.985
340.29  7.57    6.7344
340.7   7.57    5.9146
341.1   7.57    4.4772
341.5   7.57    3.2438
341.91  7.57    3.042
342.31  7.57    -0.42691
342.72  7.57    15.367
343.12  6.565   10.732
343.12  6.9     1.8768
343.12  7.235   29.059
342.72  6.565   -0.80049
342.31  6.565   -2.5909
341.91  6.565   -2.2497
341.5   6.565   -1.029
341.1   6.565   0.80188
340.7   6.565   2.9256
340.29  6.565   6.4205
342.72  6.9    -0.42877
342.31  6.9    -2.6721
341.91  6.9    -2.3757
341.5   6.9     0.30311
341.1   6.9     2.1658
340.7   6.9     4.1106
340.29  6.9     6.9719
342.72  7.235   -0.46361
342.31  7.235   -1.4547
341.91  7.235   -0.21666
341.5   7.235   2.0148
341.1   7.235   3.7058
340.7   7.235   5.3781
340.29  7.235   7.245
343.12  7.875   27.561
339.89  7.875   -3.3343
340.29  7.875   9.6077
340.7   7.875   5.2775
341.1   7.875   3.9955
341.5   7.875   3.5125
341.91  7.875   2.8382
342.31  7.875   4.3776
342.72  7.875   5.7794
303.48  7.7885  36.859
310.52  8.0168  -12.83
310.47  7.8446  -41.429
310.71  7.8359  -8.107
310.66  7.985   -47.005
311.1   7.6971  32.156
310.93  7.7585  7.1003
324.99  7.875   -14.076
325.23  7.875   220.23
325.46  7.875   190.55
325.28  8.0495  192.23
332.6   7.9809  -46.551
332.67  7.8039  -10.075
332.43  7.7979  -9.2852
332.48  7.9481  -43.534
317.66  7.875   89.542
317.89  7.875   83.653
318.13  7.875   -41.613
318.03  7.7332  -44.357
317.49  7.7261  111.58
317.88  7.7324  26.31
317.39  7.6839  132.47
339.69  7.8002  -11.625
339.57  7.7416  -6.3272
317.95  8.0495  2.26E+02
300     10.63   7.44E-02
300     10.33   -2.23E-02
300     10.43   1.13E-02
300     10.53   -4.92E-02
303.2   10.63   4.30E-02
300.1   10.63   6.13E-02
300.2   10.63   9.86E-02
300.3   10.63   0.17853
300.4   10.63   0.31268
300.5   10.63   0.46389
300.6   10.63   0.64052
300.7   10.63   0.82014
300.8   10.63   1.0203
300.9   10.63   1.2028
301     10.63   1.379
301.1   10.63   1.5212
301.2   10.63   1.6567
301.3   10.63   1.752
301.4   10.63   1.8268
301.5   10.63   1.85
301.6   10.63   1.8471
301.7   10.63   1.7958
301.8   10.63   1.7292
301.9   10.63   1.6171
302     10.63   1.4818
302.1   10.63   1.3048
302.2   10.63   1.1383
302.3   10.63   0.93875
302.4   10.63   0.75103
302.5   10.63   0.54922
302.6   10.63   0.3717
302.7   10.63   0.20346
302.8   10.63   1.14E-01
302.9   10.63   3.81E-02
303     10.63   3.52E-02
303.1   10.63   -4.37E-03
303.21  10.55   1.20E-02
303.21  10.47   1.62E-02
303.22  10.39   9.62E-02
303.22  10.31   0.2572
300.14  10.383  0.20705
302.62  10.367  1.2121
302.56  10.412  1.2042
301.04  10.367  1.7464
301.21  10.284  1.8064
300.88  10.377  1.5567
301.37  10.387  2.0338
303.01  10.464  0.30355
303.05  10.377  3.93E-01
303.1   10.548  5.77E-02
303.11  10.467  1.38E-01
300.1   10.533  6.82E-02
300.2   10.546  0.20389
300.3   10.55   0.3713
300.41  10.533  0.5932
300.5   10.521  0.79999
300.6   10.524  1.0275
300.7   10.536  1.2381
300.8   10.549  1.4836
300.9   10.543  1.7115
301     10.54   1.9023
301.1   10.547  2.1033
301.2   10.551  2.2727
301.3   10.553  2.4081
301.4   10.545  2.4614
301.5   10.542  2.4893
301.59  10.544  2.4955
301.69  10.534  2.4197
301.79  10.523  2.3207
301.89  10.528  2.2193
302     10.538  2.072
302.12  10.525  1.846
302.22  10.524  1.6402
302.32  10.536  1.4216
302.42  10.541  1.1985
302.51  10.554  0.96311
302.61  10.568  0.70543
302.71  10.561  0.53457
302.8   10.553  0.39511
302.9   10.55   0.25958
303     10.547  0.14588
300.4   10.313  0.80901
300.12  10.446  0.12256
301.18  10.388  1.899
300.77  10.311  1.4284
300.23  10.463  0.30065
302.03  10.325  1.953
302.42  10.316  1.6433
302.86  10.297  0.99736
303.01  10.417  0.39695
300.31  10.484  0.41888
300.38  10.437  0.62914
300.51  10.409  0.90951
300.61  10.414  1.0985
300.72  10.445  1.303
300.8   10.481  1.4618
300.88  10.45   1.5944
301.01  10.451  1.7904
301.11  10.467  1.9533
301.2   10.477  2.0976
301.3   10.484  2.2218
301.4   10.462  2.219
301.5   10.433  2.1855
301.58  10.475  2.3083
301.66  10.44   2.1997
301.78  10.415  2.1208
301.9   10.419  2.0497
302     10.474  2.004
302.12  10.418  1.8533
302.28  10.417  1.6215
302.35  10.454  1.4783
302.45  10.436  1.3462
302.54  10.489  1.0508
302.61  10.516  0.8429
302.69  10.488  0.76339
302.79  10.471  0.63789
302.89  10.474  0.45335
302.86  10.409  0.66702
302.73  10.419  0.86956
302.8   10.348  0.94223
302.63  10.447  0.99908
300.32  10.384  0.54091
301.22  10.436  2.0213
301.29  10.42   2.0673
301.52  10.373  2.0693
301.65  10.316  2.0084
301.33  10.346  1.94E+00
339.92  10.63   8.69E-04
339.9   10.31   0.37022
339.9   10.39   1.58E-01
339.91  10.47   3.98E-02
339.91  10.55   -6.65E-03
343.12  10.63   6.52E-03
340.02  10.63   8.97E-03
340.12  10.63   5.69E-02
340.22  10.63   0.17204
340.32  10.63   0.3397
340.42  10.63   0.52127
340.52  10.63   0.74431
340.62  10.63   1.0025
340.72  10.63   1.2207
340.82  10.63   1.433
340.92  10.63   1.6219
341.02  10.63   1.7833
341.12  10.63   1.9141
341.22  10.63   2.0101
341.32  10.63   2.0679
341.42  10.63   2.0877
341.52  10.63   2.0721
341.62  10.63   2.024
341.72  10.63   1.9454
341.82  10.63   1.8368
341.92  10.63   1.7029
342.02  10.63   1.5429
342.12  10.63   1.3627
342.22  10.63   1.1666
342.32  10.63   0.96249
342.42  10.63   0.75952
342.52  10.63   0.56844
342.62  10.63   0.39324
342.72  10.63   0.23194
342.82  10.63   1.06E-01
342.92  10.63   2.75E-02
343.02  10.63   1.00E-02
343.12  10.53   -9.16E-03
343.12  10.43   1.42E-02
343.12  10.33   0.22316
340.81  10.354  1.7624
341.63  10.349  1.8942
341.15  10.351  1.9181
340.99  10.378  1.9036
340.87  10.415  1.8649
340.58  10.354  1.5442
340.69  10.459  1.6537
340.9   10.474  1.9947
340.97  10.448  2.0262
341.06  10.425  2.0703
341.3   10.428  2.2093
341.43  10.435  2.2537
341.54  10.429  2.2125
341.69  10.401  2.0497
341.81  10.387  1.9382
342.01  10.368  1.7414
342.03  10.456  1.8583
342.04  10.481  1.8966
342.1   10.477  1.7877
342.19  10.37   1.564
342.24  10.43   1.5453
342.52  10.392  1.1104
342.7   10.448  0.74415
342.78  10.495  0.50631
342.52  10.482  1.012
342.39  10.49   1.249
342.2   10.511  1.661
342.11  10.521  1.8456
341.77  10.459  2.1955
341.66  10.475  2.3372
341.55  10.488  2.452
341.43  10.495  2.508
341.32  10.494  2.4814
341.21  10.49   2.403
341.1   10.493  2.323
340.91  10.518  2.1045
340.8   10.516  1.8997
342.73  10.316  0.93347
342.32  10.305  1.4565
341.9   10.3    1.7014
340.35  10.374  1.137
340.64  10.291  1.6669
341.04  10.296  1.7904
341.47  10.292  1.7667
342.99  10.469  2.02E-01
343 10.546  8.24E-02
342.9   10.553  0.19659
342.81  10.564  0.3294
342.71  10.571  0.48802
342.61  10.563  0.71036
342.51  10.556  0.94208
342.4   10.561  1.213
342.31  10.564  1.4526
342.21  10.568  1.7088
342.11  10.571  1.9427
342.02  10.566  2.1474
341.92  10.555  2.2974
341.84  10.539  2.3828
341.75  10.538  2.4965
341.64  10.551  2.6693
341.54  10.557  2.7656
341.43  10.56   2.8071
341.32  10.561  2.7834
341.21  10.561  2.7033
341.12  10.561  2.5882
341.02  10.566  2.4415
340.92  10.572  2.2549
340.81  10.571  2.0103
340.71  10.573  1.7345
340.6   10.577  1.4327
340.54  10.592  1.2352
340.49  10.568  1.0975
340.41  10.548  0.94499
340.29  10.541  0.67503
340.19  10.531  0.44871
340.09  10.463  0.39038
340.05  10.541  0.17012
340.09  10.405  0.52875
340.26  10.304  1.1729
340.27  10.449  0.82864
342.87  10.476  0.37145
340.48  10.426  1.2918
342.79  10.395  0.63981
342.71  10.522  0.59115
342.65  10.495  0.73988
342.29  10.497  1.4806
342.02  10.511  1.9995
341.95  10.471  2.0209
341.92  10.436  1.9567
341.01  10.506  2.2349
340.69  10.514  1.6577
340.58  10.527  1.3855
340.52  10.474  1.2945
342.37  10.428  1.3384
341.35  10.361  1.9814
341.19  10.421  2.1443
340.83  10.458  1.8647
342.16  10.454  1.6649
342.08  10.42   1.735
342.97  10.415  0.30403
341.54  10.383  2.0512
340.74  10.404  1.72E+00
300     10.73   1.27E-02
300.1   10.73   1.65E-02
300.2   10.73   5.13E-02
300.3   10.73   7.32E-02
300.4   10.73   0.14185
300.5   10.73   0.21187
300.6   10.73   0.31625
300.7   10.73   0.40977
300.8   10.73   0.52756
300.9   10.73   0.62278
301     10.73   0.73165
301.1   10.73   0.80773
301.2   10.73   0.8922
301.3   10.73   0.93811
301.4   10.73   0.98849
301.5   10.73   0.99441
301.6   10.73   1.0032
301.7   10.73   0.96685
301.8   10.73   0.93579
301.9   10.73   0.86031
302     10.73   0.79325
302.1   10.73   0.68564
302.2   10.73   0.59614
302.3   10.73   0.47064
302.4   10.73   0.37297
302.5   10.73   0.24961
302.6   10.73   1.69E-01
302.7   10.73   7.29E-02
302.8   10.73   5.15E-02
302.9   10.73   -9.61E-04
303     10.73   2.77E-02
303.1   10.73   -2.09E-02
303.2   10.73   3.78E-02
303.25  10.73   -0.27367
303.35  10.73   0.20291
303.45  10.73   0.57616
303.55  10.73   2.069
303.65  10.73   4.9688
303.75  10.73   9.1
303.85  10.73   14.067
303.95  10.73   19.608
304.05  10.73   25.296
304.15  10.73   30.95
304.25  10.73   36.328
304.35  10.73   41.247
304.45  10.73   45.359
304.55  10.73   48.753
304.65  10.73   51.133
304.75  10.73   52.466
304.85  10.73   52.545
304.95  10.73   51.345
305.05  10.73   48.646
305.15  10.73   44.563
305.25  10.73   39.039
305.35  10.73   32.183
305.45  10.73   24.024
305.55  10.73   14.681
305.65  10.73   6.5082
305.75  10.73   3.5687
305.85  10.73   2.43
305.95  10.73   1.6805
306.05  10.73   0.89896
306.15  10.73   0.40358
306.25  10.73   -0.36678
306.35  10.73   -1.1368
306.45  10.73   -1.7695
306.55  10.73   -1.6985
306.65  10.73   -0.76552
306.75  10.73   2.6864
306.85  10.73   8.7486
306.95  10.73   24.246
307.05  10.73   -14
307.15  10.73   205.35
307.25  10.73   -669.92
307.35  10.73   -733.08
307.45  10.73   106.76
307.55  10.73   8.5799
307.65  10.73   26.862
307.75  10.73   17.118
307.85  10.73   9.4006
307.95  10.73   6.9132
308.05  10.73   5.2612
308.15  10.73   5.5599
308.25  10.73   6.2825
308.35  10.73   8.9948
308.45  10.73   12.508
308.55  10.73   19.15
308.65  10.73   33.46
308.75  10.73   -5.9937
308.85  10.73   248.84
308.95  10.73   -592.81
309.05  10.73   -641.05
309.15  10.73   172.48
309.25  10.73   38.444
309.35  10.73   54.649
309.45  10.73   41.032
309.55  10.73   34.246
309.65  10.73   30.741
309.75  10.73   28.975
309.85  10.73   26.816
309.95  10.73   24.169
310.05  10.73   20.266
310.15  10.73   15.685
310.25  10.73   10.372
310.35  10.73   5.6022
310.45  10.73   2.5823
310.55  10.73   1.3075
310.58  10.73   69.714
310.68  10.73   44.583
310.78  10.73   259.28
310.88  10.73   -546.31
310.98  10.73   -600.7
311.08  10.73   231.48
311.18  10.73   165.97
311.28  10.73   194.11
311.38  10.73   174.97
311.48  10.73   154.96
311.58  10.73   138.46
311.68  10.73   124.56
311.78  10.73   112.19
311.88  10.73   100.89
311.98  10.73   90.363
312.08  10.73   80.823
312.18  10.73   72.248
312.28  10.73   64.979
312.38  10.73   59.003
312.48  10.73   54.68
312.58  10.73   52.058
312.68  10.73   51.374
312.78  10.73   52.606
312.88  10.73   56.297
312.98  10.73   62.713
313.08  10.73   72.453
313.18  10.73   86.081
313.28  10.73   104.48
313.38  10.73   128.2
313.48  10.73   158.21
313.58  10.73   195.07
313.68  10.73   238.81
313.78  10.73   287.17
313.88  10.73   336.55
313.98  10.73   382.42
314.08  10.73   418.03
314.18  10.73   437.39
314.28  10.73   437.22
314.38  10.73   418.83
314.48  10.73   385.67
314.58  10.73   342.68
314.68  10.73   294.99
314.78  10.73   247.7
314.88  10.73   204.64
314.98  10.73   167.72
315.08  10.73   137.43
315.18  10.73   112.96
315.28  10.73   93.787
315.38  10.73   78.595
315.48  10.73   66.729
315.58  10.73   57.098
315.68  10.73   49.423
315.78  10.73   42.934
315.88  10.73   37.582
315.98  10.73   32.784
316.08  10.73   28.696
316.18  10.73   24.897
316.28  10.73   21.623
316.38  10.73   18.527
316.48  10.73   15.957
316.58  10.73   13.513
316.68  10.73   11.528
316.78  10.73   9.5522
316.88  10.73   7.965
316.98  10.73   6.3829
317.08  10.73   5.1411
317.18  10.73   3.8444
317.28  10.73   2.8892
317.38  10.73   1.8354
317.48  10.73   1.1398
317.58  10.73   0.39599
317.68  10.73   2.31E-01
317.78  10.73   -4.36E-02
317.88  10.73   0.44288
317.91  10.73   0.94026
318.01  10.73   2.9174
318.11  10.73   6.3947
318.21  10.73   12.699
318.31  10.73   19.929
318.41  10.73   27.838
318.51  10.73   35.365
318.61  10.73   42.813
318.71  10.73   49.607
318.81  10.73   56.786
318.91  10.73   65.128
319.01  10.73   76.906
319.11  10.73   94.335
319.21  10.73   67.772
319.31  10.73   277.5
319.41  10.73   -572.29
319.51  10.73   -637.02
319.61  10.73   158.45
319.71  10.73   31.28
319.81  10.73   35.63
319.91  10.73   21.18
320.01  10.73   14.364
320.11  10.73   9.7189
320.21  10.73   6.664
320.31  10.73   4.0881
320.41  10.73   2.5782
320.51  10.73   1.009
320.61  10.73   -0.7218
320.71  10.73   -2.3668
320.81  10.73   -2.9873
320.91  10.73   -2.8702
321.01  10.73   -0.87178
321.11  10.73   9.973
321.21  10.73   -29.25
321.31  10.73   174.87
321.41  10.73   -793.41
321.51  10.73   -867.12
321.61  10.73   42.869
321.71  10.73   -19.61
321.81  10.73   1.7266
321.91  10.73   -5.6193
322.01  10.73   -8.2422
322.11  10.73   -8.2872
322.21  10.73   -7.6938
322.31  10.73   -4.1787
322.41  10.73   -0.88428
322.51  10.73   2.4453
322.61  10.73   7.2943
322.71  10.73   14.214
322.81  10.73   28.655
322.91  10.73   -8.4214
323.01  10.73   245.52
323.11  10.73   -589.33
323.21  10.73   -657.84
323.31  10.73   162.64
323.41  10.73   43.606
323.51  10.73   63.093
323.61  10.73   55.416
323.71  10.73   49.543
323.81  10.73   47.985
323.91  10.73   47.731
324.01  10.73   47.193
324.11  10.73   45.588
324.21  10.73   42.896
324.31  10.73   39.1
324.41  10.73   34.354
324.51  10.73   28.827
324.61  10.73   22.887
324.71  10.73   16.8
324.81  10.73   11.026
324.91  10.73   6.1583
325.01  10.73   2.6536
325.11  10.73   1.0525
325.21  10.73   1.06E-01
325.24  10.73   3.12E-02
325.34  10.73   3.30E-02
325.44  10.73   2.26E-02
325.54  10.73   2.42E-02
325.64  10.73   3.31E-02
325.74  10.73   4.11E-02
325.84  10.73   4.36E-02
325.94  10.73   4.20E-02
326.04  10.73   4.31E-02
326.14  10.73   4.02E-02
326.24  10.73   3.92E-02
326.34  10.73   4.86E-02
326.44  10.73   7.17E-02
326.54  10.73   0.15178
326.64  10.73   0.45153
326.74  10.73   1.0454
326.84  10.73   1.8817
326.94  10.73   2.9651
327.04  10.73   4.3045
327.14  10.73   5.9183
327.24  10.73   7.8381
327.34  10.73   10.14
327.44  10.73   12.893
327.54  10.73   16.327
327.64  10.73   20.634
327.74  10.73   26.026
327.84  10.73   32.868
327.94  10.73   41.553
328.04  10.73   52.448
328.14  10.73   65.903
328.24  10.73   82.254
328.34  10.73   101.43
328.44  10.73   122.58
328.54  10.73   144.13
328.64  10.73   163.96
328.74  10.73   179.41
328.84  10.73   188.22
328.94  10.73   189.03
329.04  10.73   181.34
329.14  10.73   166.76
329.24  10.73   147.86
329.34  10.73   127.01
329.44  10.73   106.66
329.54  10.73   88.21
329.64  10.73   72.311
329.74  10.73   59.275
329.84  10.73   48.842
329.94  10.73   40.457
330.04  10.73   33.826
330.14  10.73   28.542
330.24  10.73   24.333
330.34  10.73   20.984
330.44  10.73   18.225
330.54  10.73   15.889
330.64  10.73   13.884
330.74  10.73   12.152
330.84  10.73   10.583
330.94  10.73   9.1987
331.04  10.73   7.9605
331.14  10.73   6.8433
331.24  10.73   5.8498
331.34  10.73   4.9814
331.44  10.73   4.2384
331.54  10.73   3.5846
331.64  10.73   3.0084
331.74  10.73   2.4839
331.84  10.73   2.0031
331.94  10.73   1.5633
332.04  10.73   1.1539
332.14  10.73   0.78454
332.24  10.73   0.47189
332.34  10.73   2.32E-01
332.44  10.73   9.02E-02
332.54  10.73   2.85E-02
332.57  10.73   0.14486
332.67  10.73   0.15999
332.77  10.73   0.22171
332.87  10.73   0.22444
332.97  10.73   0.22736
333.07  10.73   0.22251
333.17  10.73   0.1857
333.27  10.73   1.31E-01
333.37  10.73   8.99E-02
333.47  10.73   3.70E-02
333.57  10.73   -5.35E-02
333.67  10.73   -0.10805
333.77  10.73   -0.14844
333.87  10.73   -0.22052
333.97  10.73   -0.27432
334.07  10.73   -0.29479
334.17  10.73   -0.32501
334.27  10.73   -0.35384
334.37  10.73   -0.35748
334.47  10.73   -0.343
334.57  10.73   -0.31643
334.67  10.73   -0.25857
334.77  10.73   -0.21492
334.87  10.73   -0.1033
334.97  10.73   0.11394
335.07  10.73   0.44323
335.17  10.73   1.3367
335.27  10.73   4.5682
335.37  10.73   10.577
335.47  10.73   18.412
335.57  10.73   28.015
335.67  10.73   39.294
335.77  10.73   51.79
335.87  10.73   64.651
335.97  10.73   76.815
336.07  10.73   86.543
336.17  10.73   92.423
336.27  10.73   93.432
336.37  10.73   89.91
336.47  10.73   82.6
336.57  10.73   72.792
336.67  10.73   61.718
336.77  10.73   50.687
336.87  10.73   40.607
336.97  10.73   32.02
337.07  10.73   24.995
337.17  10.73   19.407
337.27  10.73   15.063
337.37  10.73   11.712
337.47  10.73   9.1262
337.57  10.73   7.1125
337.67  10.73   5.5339
337.77  10.73   4.2786
337.87  10.73   3.2661
337.97  10.73   2.4365
338.07  10.73   1.7564
338.17  10.73   1.206
338.27  10.73   0.76933
338.37  10.73   0.44254
338.47  10.73   0.22235
338.57  10.73   1.09E-01
338.67  10.73   9.17E-02
338.77  10.73   9.77E-02
338.87  10.73   0.1282
338.97  10.73   0.1968
339.07  10.73   0.2883
339.17  10.73   0.37495
339.27  10.73   0.43339
339.37  10.73   0.44948
339.47  10.73   0.4137
339.57  10.73   0.32584
339.67  10.73   2.03E-01
339.77  10.73   9.92E-02
339.87  10.73   5.11E-02
339.92  10.73   -4.57E-03
340.02  10.73   8.42E-03
340.12  10.73   2.77E-02
340.22  10.73   7.63E-02
340.32  10.73   0.15954
340.42  10.73   0.26613
340.52  10.73   0.39279
340.62  10.73   0.52723
340.72  10.73   0.65887
340.82  10.73   0.78107
340.92  10.73   0.89223
341.02  10.73   0.98805
341.12  10.73   1.0652
341.22  10.73   1.1222
341.32  10.73   1.1573
341.42  10.73   1.1705
341.52  10.73   1.1632
341.62  10.73   1.1359
341.72  10.73   1.0894
341.82  10.73   1.0251
341.92  10.73   0.94471
342.02  10.73   0.85088
342.12  10.73   0.74606
342.22  10.73   0.63343
342.32  10.73   0.51676
342.42  10.73   0.40033
342.52  10.73   0.28942
342.62  10.73   0.18989
342.72  10.73   1.06E-01
342.82  10.73   4.65E-02
342.92  10.73   1.43E-02
343.02  10.73   2.60E-03
343.12  10.73   -4.48E-03
```

I have two different codes. first one is:

```
filename = 'node_coordinate.xlsx';
sheet = 1;
XRange = 'B2:B6194';
YRange = 'C2:C6194';
ZRange = 'I2:I6194';

x = xlsread(filename,sheet,XRange);
y = xlsread(filename,sheet,YRange);
z = xlsread(filename,sheet,ZRange);

[X, Y] = meshgrid(sort(x), sort(y));
Z = griddata(x, y, z, X, Y);

figure(8)
surf(X,Y,Z)

contourf(X,Y,Z)
colormap cool
colorbar('location','EastOutside')
beta =0.4;
brighten(beta);
axis square
```

I hope something like this:[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVNYB.png][1]
But I get this:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWlTo.png][1]

Also my second code is:

```
x = table2array(readtable('node_coordinate.xlsx','Range','B2:B6194'));
y = table2array(readtable('node_coordinate.xlsx','Range','C2:C6194'));
z = table2array(readtable('node_coordinate.xlsx','Range','I2:I6194'));

figure(1)
p_h=plot3(x,z,y,'o');grid 


rangeZ=floor(min(z)):3:ceil(max(z));   %3 is the spacing I have chosen.
rangeX=floor(min(x)):0.5:ceil(max(x)); %0.5 is the spacing I have chosen

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

Y=griddata(x,z,y,X,Z,'cubic');

pause

surf(X,Z,Y) 
xlabel('x'),ylabel('z'),zlabel('y')

cs=contourf(X,Z,Y);
colormap cool
colorbar('location','EastOutside')
beta =0.4;
brighten(beta);
axis square
```

But it takes lots of time and makes matlab 'busy' for hours so I thought that it could not be correct code.

Is there anybody help?

Comment: Is this a problem with reading data from Excel or plotting? We don't have your Excel data, so write a [mcve] which doesn't depend on it if the data reading is fine. If the Excel reading isn't OK then this question isn't about plotting! Break the issue down, it will make life easier for you and us.

Comment: @Wolfie Seems data reading is ok and contour plot is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are very similar ...

I'm not exactly sure what's going on but some thoughts:

1. meshgrid combines all x and y point combinations so your second example is a better use of meshgrid (almost, just saw an error). Otherwise your grid `X` and `Y` will contain many duplicate points.

To fix the error:

```
%TODO: you'll need to define rangeY instead of rangeZ
rangeX=floor(min(x)):0.5:ceil(max(x));
[X,Y] = meshgrid(rangeX,rangeY);
```

2. I find meshgrid and contour functions confusing. To start out I'd use `scatter` for debugging.

Example code:

```
%For the original data:
sz = 5; %size of point, user preference
scatter(x,y,sz,z,'filled')

%For the new data
scatter(X(:),Y(:),sz,Z(:),'filled')
```

3. As alluded to in the first point, your second example is using z where instead you should be using y ...
4. Based on your example it looks like you want griddata to interpolate over an area where no data exist. I think griddata smooths at specified points, rather than anchoring at specified points, which could cause some issues with the holes you have in your data ...

None of these things really solves the problem of getting the contour you want. If the data are essentially evenly sampled (in a grid) already, but you just have missing points (i.e. you have some sort of sparse matrix), you could create a matrix that is the appropriate size and fill in the points you have. I'm not entirely sure how I'd do this off the top of my head but it should be relatively easy. Just to make this example clear consider you have the data points:

```
x = [0.5 0.5 1  ];
y = [0.6 1.2 0.6];
z = [4 5 6];
```

Then you could think of this as something like a 2x2 matrix with one missing/empty point so your final matrix might be:

```
Z = [4  6; ...
     5  NaN];  %<= missing point since no x = 1, y = 1.2 pair

X = [0.5 1];
Y = [0.6 1.2];
```

This comes from treating 0.5 and 1 as indices 1 and 2 for X and 0.6 and 1.2 as the indices 1 and 2 for Y.